# How to find WAN IP/External IP Address of Android device without call any web request

Tags: android

I need to find WAN IP/External IP address of android device without any web request call.I searched many sites,they conclude to send http request to www.whatismyip.com or other url.

Is there any other possibilities to get WAN IP from device without web request?

Comment: Inspect alll network devices and there ip addresses. Order them by public and private ranges. The ip in a public range is probaly the external one. If the device is in a local network over wifi, you have to make a request, otherwise you will not see the externel ip of the router between local network and internet.

Comment: Here is a good example how to get all IPs on Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503000/how-to-iterate-through-the-list-of-ipv4-network-addresses-in-java-or-android-one. Private addresses are in this ranges: a) 10.0.0.0/8  b) 172.16.0.0/12 c) 192.168.0.0/16  all other addresses are public internetadresses.

Comment: Sorry don't have time to create working example ;)